# Problems Creating correct location element in web.config for asp.net site

Tags: asp.net

I have a test site on the web that I want to block all annoymous access to except logged in users.  I also want to have annoymous access to just my login page (account/login)

I don't know how to exclude one path but even the below does not work, forgetting about the path.

```
<location path="">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="*" />
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the following web.config setting should work. Make sure you update **two Login.aspx** with your login page.

It basically does not allow anonymous access except Login page.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="~/Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```